# Img moving all column?

Tags: html, css

So i've been trying to make this gallery for a web we are making in school and it seems to work but there's a small bug when on mouse over the img as you can see in the  [gif](https://gyazo.com/1384bf22889ac98b5dde1bd89a75b98a).
I don't know if it's because of the border size or i should have used a table instead of divs. I appreciate any help.

```css
div#img {
 border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #3781FF;
    height: 140;
    width: 100;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

div#img img {
    margin: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}

div#img a:hover img {
 border-radius: 40px;
    border:0px solid #3781FF;
 text-align: center;
}

div#desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estil.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="galeria.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title> LoL - Stats </title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   //Crear un event de click
   $('ul.listado li a').click(function() {
    
    //Pasar es text a minuscules
    var textoFiltro = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"-");
    
    //mostrar tots si se pitja 
    if(textoFiltro == 'todos') 
    {
     $('div.filtros div.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    
    else
    {
     //bucle per obtenir tots es divs amb clase filtro
     $('.filtros div').each(function() {
      
      
      if(!$(this).hasClass(textoFiltro)) 
      {
       $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
      }
     
      //Mostar amb animacio fade-in
      else 
      {
       $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
      }
     });
    }
    
    return false;
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="center" style="width: 900px;background-color: #FFFFFF">

   <a href="index.html"><div id="titol">
    LoL Stats
   </div></a>

   <div id="barrabotons">
    <a href="champs.html"><div id="boto">
     Champions
     </div> </a>
     
    <a href="classi.html"><div id="boto">
     Worlds
     </div> </a>
     
    <a href="patch.html"><div id="boto">
     Patch
     </div> </a>
    
    <a href="rotacion.html"><div id="boto">
     Rotación Setmanal
     </div> </a>
   </div>

   <div id="bodydiv">
    <h1 style="color:#3781FF; text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;">Campeones</h1>
    
    <section>
    <ul class="listado">
     <li><a href="#">Todos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Magos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tanques</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Asesinos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Suports</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="filtros">
     
     <div id="img" class="asesinos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/aatrox.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc" class="asesinos">Aatrox<br>6300 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/ahri.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Ahri<br>4800 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/akali.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Akali<br>1350 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/alistar.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Alistar<br>450 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/amumu.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Ammumu<br>450 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/anivia.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Anivia<br>3150 RP</div>
     </div> 

     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/annie.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Annie<br>450 RP</div>
     </div> 

     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/ashe.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Ashe<br>450 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/azir.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Azir<br>6300 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/bard.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Bardo<br>6300 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/blitzcrank.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Blitzcrank<br>1350 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/brand.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Brand<br>3150 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/braum.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Braum<br>6300 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/caitlyn.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Caitlyn<br>4800 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img" class="magos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/cassiopea.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Cassiopeia<br>4800 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/chogath.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Cho'Gath<br>450 RP</div>
     </div>
     
     <div  id="img">
      <a><img src="img/champs/corki.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc">Corki<br>3150 RP</div>
     </div>

     
     <div  id="img" class="asesinos">
      <a><img src="img/champs/irelia.png" width="80" height="80"></a>
      <div  id="desc" class="asesinos">Irelia<br>3150 RP</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <section>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot  to add "px" for width and height properties of div#img.

```
div#img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #3781FF;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/rOvzWa)

`div#img a:hover img` have `border:0px solid #3781FF;` this is problem. this is changed to `border-color:transparent;` or `border: 2px solid #3781FF;`